# Excel Formula finding max/min values

Tags: excel

I have two columns, a X and Y column, it has data points that when graphed (200+ data points) , it graphs a hand drawn square. My duty is to find (X,y) points of the four corners. To do so, I would need to find the minimum value of X, and the maximum Y point to get the top left corner point

I will need to determine the maximum X point and maximum Y value to find the bottom left corner points and so on.

However, I am not sure how to do this, because I can find the maximum/ minimum value of X/Y, but I will not find the 4 pairs of the corners. Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: Will the sides always be parallel to the coordinate system axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sides are always parallel to coordinate system, the points are:

```
A: min(x), min(y)
B: min(x), max(y)
C: max(x), min(y)
D: max(x), max(y)
```

If the sides are not parallel, then one needs to be a bit more clever:

```
A: min(x), the value of y where x is minimum
B: the value of x where y is maximum,  max(y)
C: max(x), the value of y where x is maximum
D: the value of x where y is minimum,  min(y)
```

This only works if there is one and only one y at either min or max x, and one and only one x for min and max x.  The code needs to do all of this.

Assuming coordinates are in Sheet1, x-coordinates are in range name "x", y-coordinates in range name "y", the following code should return the corner coordinates:

```
Option Explicit
Sub addresses()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim sXMinAddress As String, sXMaxAddress As String
Dim sXMinAddressY As String, sXMaxAddressY As String
Dim xMin As Double, xMax As Double
Dim xMinY As Double, xMaxY As Double
Dim sYMinAddress As String, sYMaxAddress As String
Dim sYMinAddressX As String, sYMaxAddressX As String
Dim yMin As Double, yMax As Double
Dim yMinX As Double, yMaxX As Double
Dim testAddress As String, i As Integer

Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

sXMaxAddress = wks.Range("x").Cells(1, 1).Address
sXMinAddress = wks.Range("x").Cells(1, 1).Address
sXMaxAddressY = wks.Range(sXMaxAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address
sXMinAddressY = wks.Range(sXMinAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address
xMax = wks.Range(sXMaxAddress).Value
xMin = wks.Range(sXMinAddress).Value

sYMaxAddress = wks.Range("y").Cells(1, 2).Address
sYMinAddress = wks.Range("y").Cells(1, 2).Address
sYMaxAddressX = wks.Range(sYMaxAddress).Offset(0, -1).Address
sYMinAddressX = wks.Range(sYMinAddress).Offset(0, -1).Address
yMax = wks.Range(sYMaxAddress).Value
yMin = wks.Range(sYMinAddress).Value

For i = 2 To wks.Range("x").Count
    testAddress = wks.Range("x").Cells(i, 1).Address
    If wks.Range(testAddress).Value < xMin Then
        xMin = wks.Range(testAddress).Value
        sXMinAddress = testAddress
        sXMinAddressY = wks.Range(testAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address
        xMinY = wks.Range(sXMinAddressY).Value
    End If
    If wks.Range(testAddress).Value > xMax Then
        xMax = wks.Range(testAddress).Value
        sXMaxAddress = testAddress
        sXMaxAddressY = wks.Range(testAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address
        xMaxY = wks.Range(sXMaxAddressY).Value
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To wks.Range("y").Count
    testAddress = wks.Range("y").Cells(i, 1).Address
    If wks.Range(testAddress).Value < yMin Then
        yMin = wks.Range(testAddress).Value
        sYMinAddress = testAddress
        sYMinAddressX = wks.Range(testAddress).Offset(0, -1).Address
        yMinX = wks.Range(sYMinAddressX).Value
    End If
    If wks.Range(testAddress).Value > yMax Then
        yMax = wks.Range(testAddress).Value
        sYMaxAddress = testAddress
        sYMaxAddressX = wks.Range(testAddress).Offset(0, -1).Address
        yMaxX = wks.Range(sYMaxAddressX).Value
    End If
Next i
Debug.Print "Vertices:"
Debug.Print "A: " & xMin & ", " & xMinY
Debug.Print "B: " & xMax & ", " & xMaxY
Debug.Print "C: " & yMaxX & ", " & yMax
Debug.Print "D: " & yMinX & ", " & yMin

Debug.Print "Sheet addresses"
Debug.Print "A: " & sXMinAddress & "," & sXMinAddressY
Debug.Print "B: " & sYMaxAddressX & "," & sYMaxAddress
Debug.Print "C: " & sXMaxAddress & "," & sXMaxAddressY
Debug.Print "D: " & sYMinAddressX & "," & sYMinAddress
End Sub
```

Comment: No its not parallel, I used a pen that projected onto a table where the computer added each (x, y) so the square is unsymmetrical.

Comment: An outline of a solution for non-parallel sides is now included.

Comment: Some VBA to find the corner coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, however the data is a bit more complicated, I have tried the macro however it does not work. I am not completely clear when you say there is only one x and only one Y.

however attached is a link for one trial. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d64tm5bq2od6bka/dataa.xlsx

there are many data points and I will need the four corners points. If you plot the data points on excel, you can see it plots a unsymmetrical square. If you can help with this, that would be great.

Comment: It's not a square, it's a rhombus. Not even that, because the sides do not appear to be straight lines.  The algorithm I provided will certainly fail for curved sides; it only works with four-sided figures whose vertices are connected by straight lines.  What you're looking for, I'm guessing, is something that locates something like discontinuities in the first derivative of a function describing a side.  What's the application here, if I may ask?

Comment: I am working on a research project and part of the anaylsis is to determine the four corner points. In addition after the four corner points, I will need to determine the middle/center points between each corners (Left center point between the top left and bottom left, Top center point between top left corner and top right corner, and etc.) In total, I will need eight points for each trial.

The shape presented is hand drawn, which is why it may not look perfect or that it looks even like a rhombus.

I was looking for a simple max(if)...formula or function if that would work.

Comment: It seems clear that there is no simple max() formula for identifying vertices.  An approach that stands a better chance: find the radius of curvature of each set of three adjacent coordinates.  With a well-chosen radius threshold there may be four coordinates below that threshold - these are the vertices.  Midpoints then are easy.  I'll refrain from working on this - I've already provided a solution to the original "square" problem.  If you're looking for solution that fits the data, you're better off asking a restated, more precise question.